# Is there a generic way to get a Linq2SQL Entity by its primary key?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Ok, the short version is that I have a Linq entity from a LinqDataSourceUpdateEventArgs and I need to handle the Update manually because MS was stupid.

I can get the Table object from the data context, which allows me to, well, this:

```
var newObj = e.NewObject;

var table = FormContext.GetTable(e.NewObject.GetType());

table.Attach(newObj, e.OriginalObject);

if (BuildingObject != null)
    BuildingObject(sender, new HeirarchicalBuildObjectEventArgs(newObj));


FormContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Unfortunately, I get the exception "Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use."

Of course, the funny part is I get that on FormContext.SubmitChanges(), NOT on table.Attach()... which makes no sense to me, but whatever.

I'm thinking I need to actually get the object from the context, and attach using that instead of e.OriginalObject... OR, as a last resort, I need to get the original object and write a loop which copies the value of every property into the one I get from the data context.

Either way, I need to look up an object by it's primary key without knowing the type of the object.  Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: Ok, took a look through .NET Reflector and I'm noticing that, among other things, LinqDataSourceView attaches the OLD data object and then copies all the values into it... but that apparently skips the associations.  Going to try attaching the old object and copying values over, I guess...

The really funny part?  I wrote a function to copy properties from one entity instance to another a long time ago, and it contains this comment:

//We can't copy associations, and probably shouldn't

Sometimes I wish my comments were more thorough...

EDIT EDIT:  Ok, so once again the correct answer is: I asked the wrong question!

The correct code is:

```
        var newObj = e.NewObject;

        var table = FormContext.GetTable(e.NewObject.GetType());

        if (BuildingObject != null)
            BuildingObject(sender, new HeirarchicalBuildObjectEventArgs(newObj));

        table.Attach(newObj, e.OriginalObject);

        FormContext.SubmitChanges();


        e.Cancel = true;
```

I originally was trying to attach after BuildingObject, but got some other error and moved the attach statement in an effort to correct it.  (I think because I was calling the wrong version of Attach.  Or maybe I had the arguments reversed...)

Comment: How can you look up an entity if you don't know its type?

Comment: I can get the table without knowing the type.  Somewhere in there Linq2SQL knows something is flagged as primary key... I shouldn't need to know, especially as I have a shallow copy of the object I could use to find it.  In fact, things like LinqDataSource somehow manage to do this... otherwise they wouldn't be able to perform the behavior I'm trying to rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use implementation of generic repository from Sutekishop, open source e-commerce web shop built with asp.net mvc and L2S.
It has nice GetByID for generic type T, which relies on L2S attributes on model classes. This is the part that does the job:

```
public virtual T GetById(int id)
{
    var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");

    var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
        (
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(
                itemParameter,
                typeof(T).GetPrimaryKey().Name
                ),
            Expression.Constant(id)
            ),
        new[] { itemParameter }
        );
     return GetAll().Where(whereExpression).Single();
}
```

and extension method that looks for primary key property; as you can see it expects "Column" attribute with "IsPrimaryKey" on class property. Extension methods:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPrimaryKey(this Type entityType) {
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in entityType.GetProperties()) {
        if (property.IsPrimaryKey()) {
            if (property.PropertyType != typeof (int)) {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Primary key, '{0}', of type '{1}' is not int", property.Name, entityType));
            }
            return property;
        }
    }
    throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("No primary key defined for type {0}", entityType.Name));
} 

public static TAttribute GetAttributeOf<TAttribute>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
    object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true);
    if (attributes.Length == 0)
        return default(TAttribute);
    return (TAttribute)attributes[0];
}

public static bool IsPrimaryKey(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
    var columnAttribute = propertyInfo.GetAttributeOf<ColumnAttribute>();
    if (columnAttribute == null) return false;
    return columnAttribute.IsPrimaryKey;
}
```

All credits for this code goes to [Mike Hadlow](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/)! Whole implementation can be found in [sutekishop source](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/)

Comment: Giving you the answer because it looks most like what would work, for the original question, had I gotten through implementing it before I realized my real problem.  Technically I wouldn't have the ID, but pretty sure I could use these functions to get it...

Comment: well yes, i didn't quite understood your question so I focused on title. If hope, at least, this code would help someday!

Comment: This is actually very wrong; you shouldn't rely on attributes here - POCO is supported too. You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880090/c-linq-sql-an-updatebyid-method-for-the-repository-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following to get the Entity by ID:

(*Where `TLinqEntity` is the type of class that is generated by LinqToSql...and is a Generic Parameter in the class itself.*)

```
    protected TLinqEntity GetByID(object id, DataContext dataContextInstance)
    {
        return dataContextInstance.GetTable<TLinqEntity>()
            .SingleOrDefault(GetIDWhereExpression(id));
    }

    static Expression<Func<TLinqEntity, bool>> GetIDWhereExpression(object id)
    {
        var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLinqEntity), "item");
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TLinqEntity, bool>>
            (
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(
                    itemParameter,
                    TypeExtensions.GetPrimaryKey(typeof(TLinqEntity)).Name
                    ),
                Expression.Constant(id)
                ),
            new[] { itemParameter }
            );
    }

    static PropertyInfo GetPrimaryKey(Type entityType)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            var attributes = (ColumnAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true);
            if (attributes.Length == 1)
            {
                ColumnAttribute columnAttribute = attributes[0];
                if (columnAttribute.IsPrimaryKey)
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType != typeof(int))
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Primary key, '{0}', of type '{1}' is not int",
                            property.Name, entityType));
                    }
                    return property;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("No primary key defined for type {0}", entityType.Name));
    }
```

---

This is the Update Method (thanks to [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880090/c-linq-sql-an-updatebyid-method-for-the-repository-pattern)):

```
    public virtual void Update(DataContext dataContext, TLinqEntity obj)
    {
        // get the row from the database using the meta-model
        MetaType meta = dataContext.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(TLinqEntity)).RowType;
        if (meta.IdentityMembers.Count != 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Composite identity not supported");
        string idName = meta.IdentityMembers[0].Member.Name;
        var id = obj.GetType().GetProperty(idName).GetValue(obj, null);

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLinqEntity), "row");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLinqEntity, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(param, idName),
                Expression.Constant(id, typeof(int))), param);

        object dbRow = dataContext.GetTable<TLinqEntity>().Single(lambda);

        foreach (MetaDataMember member in meta.DataMembers)
        {
            // don't copy ID or timstamp/rowversion
            if (member.IsPrimaryKey || member.IsVersion) continue;
            // (perhaps exclude associations too)

            member.MemberAccessor.SetBoxedValue(
                ref dbRow, member.MemberAccessor.GetBoxedValue(obj));
        }
        dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Might work, but I'd really rather not have to go back and start adding things to every class we decide to use this technique with... and really if I were going to do that I'd just create an Interface that requires a specific data member for obtaining the primary key.

Comment: It does work, because I use it for every project I use when implementing Linq2Sql

Comment: according this comment "// (perhaps exclude associations too)" - yes, associations also should be excluded, because it will change your current values